# Cannot Solve "Configuration Does not Exist..." Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm just trying to apply Option Pattern and I coded that in ConfigureServices:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

However VS gives the error "The name Configuration does not exist in the current context."

I added almost all the namespaces such as using System.Configuration and using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. Closed the VS and opened it again. Delete the code and coded again but still I get the same error and Configuration is always highlighted with red.

Do you know what's going on here?

Comment: You need to add a field or property `IConfiguration Configuration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `Configuration` is a property. You need to add

```
private readonly IConfiguration Configuration { get; set;}

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```